# Login popup for In App Purchase (Automatically pick account for In App Purchase)

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, payment

Am using In App Purchase in my app. It is working fine but client posted a requirement that, while purchasing it prompts a popup to enter a password of the account. But client says that it must not be the case account must be automatically picked up. like the following image.

Am not getting any solution regarding that please help me out.

[image]

Comment: I dont think so its possible. Verifcation is necessary before buying something

Answer (score 0):

Developers don't have any control over whether Apple prompts for a login or not when authorizing in-app purchases. If Apple needs account verification or if a user has certain settings enabled it will prompt for a password.

Comment: I agree with you but above image is from Tinder it just prompts the account and there is no need to enter password

Comment: Most of the time this is the behavior, and Apple won't prompt for a password. As a developer there's nothing you can do to code for this.